# Setting up emitter to text and morphing to another text?

Tags: animation, physics, text-object, collision

I am wanting to emit particles to form a text and then for the text to morph into another text, and to do it in Blender 2.81.
Are there any experts out there with the know how to accomplish this. I am a beginner and basically have only gotten as far as have my text typed up ready to go.

Comment: Here is a great youtube video that will walk you through exactly what you're wanting: https://youtu.be/lPCs4XbGth8